# Why did Redstone still fail after Katherine Johnson's successful calculation?

Tags: hidden-figures

In Hidden Figures, from 43:00 onwards, [Katherine Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katherine_Johnson) appears to have successfully solved the calculation error that was leading to the failure of the Redstone rocket.

[image]

Later on, at around 56:50, footage is shown of the Redstone rocket tests exploding. Why did the Redstone rockets fail even after Katherine Johnson had corrected the issue that was previously causing them to fail?